# Copy data from one sheet to another using variable references in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy data from column H into a new sheet. I'd like the copy paste location in the new sheet to depend on what option is selected from a drop down menu in C2 and a drop down menu in E2. The new sheet has a table with the options from C2 and E2 in columns. I need the code to look at what is in C2 & E2, find that location in the table and copy paste.

I'm able to get it to reference the type and copy it from that, but when i want it to reference both the type AND the month. It dies.

```
Sub COPY_TRANSPOSE()
'this program looks for type and month in sheet Data
'If the type and month are found, copies H6:H1000 in sheet Data and paste it to sheet table

Dim rng_source As Range
Dim rng_dest As Range
Dim cell As Range
Const Type_Cell = "A1" 'Cell that refers to the type
Cont Month = "E2" 'month


Set rng_source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("H6:H1000")
Set rng_dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table").Range("A2:A1000")
Set rng_dest2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table").Range("C2:C1000")
Set cell = rng_dest.Find(what:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table").Range(Type_Cell).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set cell2 = rng_dest2.Find(what:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("table").Range(Month).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not cell And cell2 Is Nothing Then

rng_source.copy

Sheets("table").Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 7)).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Else
MsgBox ("error")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I acknowledge your approach is a code-based one: have you considered doing this as a formula? I think you can probably do that with a single relatively simple formula, but understand you may have reasons to do as a macro

Comment: I'm going to have multiple users adding in data on sheet 1, which will be cleared each time one of the options is changed. I might be being v. dense, but I could only think of an If/vlookup/index method, which would not work as with the data being changed each time an option is changed.

Comment: noted ok, but you would not need a formula on sheet1, the formula would be on sheet 2 only referring to sheet 1 and would be non-intrusive on sheet 1 - if i understand correctly the goal is to have sheet 1 independent and populate sheet 2 as the dependent sheet. Maybe i dont fully understand what you want to do

Comment: I think we are almost on the same page :). I think my concern/problem is coming from say a user comes in and changes lemons to apples and march to feb, and then inputs data. How would the sheet2 respond to that?

Comment: the lemons/march value would go to zero and the apples/feb value would be what they type in new - it would automatically show the correct value and zero the previous

Comment: Ah, I need it to hold whatever was typed in for lemons/march in the table, and then copy whatever was added for apples/feb into whereever that is on the table.

Comment: ok and if someone changes the value for an already populated field that adds or overwrites, so in your example Lemon/March/52 changed by another user to Lemon/March/17 does that then go to 17 or 69?

Comment: Goes to 17, hopefully.... :')

Answer (score 0):

try this pls

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
  Dim wsIn As Worksheet: Set wsIn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Dim wsOut As Worksheet: Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
  
  'following your range hard coding here
  Dim rOut As Range: Set rOut = wsOut.Range("a2:c1000")
  
  'strip values
  Dim s_fruit As String: s_fruit = wsIn.Range("c2").Value
  Dim s_month As String: s_month = wsIn.Range("e2").Value
  Dim d_value As Double: d_value = wsIn.Range("h4").Value
  
  'filter to get row of interest
  rOut.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=s_fruit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
  rOut.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=s_month, Operator:=xlFilterValues

  ' only attempt to set value if we get strictly 1 row filtered
  If rOut.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count = 1 Then
      rOut.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3).Value = d_value
  End If
  
  'remove filter
  rOut.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: I've updated the initial question with what I have done so far, does this help clarify what i want to do?

Comment: have you run the code i put here? what happened?

Comment: Yes, it was only ever updating D3. Not sure why!

Comment: I just changed the setting line     `rOut.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3).Value = d_value
` try that - sure it  will work ok now ...

Comment: Great success, now how do I get it to copy a whole column of data and transpose it to the found row? Apologies, I realise I should have mentioned this initially but was wary of over complicating my question...

Comment: sorry dont fully follow - screenshots? tks